# How to recover from lifting something very heavy?

Tags: weights

I lifted a 30 kilogram bag upstairs one step at time- properly using my legs and centre of gravity . My core is solid from situps and cross crunches.  I have weightlifting 4 years using 8 kilogram weight every second day mostly arms and chest. However I just recovered from a ligament tear in the back and side and rib pain when lying down. I didn't hurt my back but there is some stress at base of the spine. How to recover from this experience at my limits?

Comment: By not asking strangers on the internet for medical advice. Go to a professional

Comment: Frankly, I’d deadlift with proper form to recover. I’d argue that sit-ups and crunches do relatively little for your core and that heavy squats, deadlifts, and presses will build a much more stable trunk. Strongmen who compete do virtually zero crunches and carry A LOT more than 30kg through rigorous obstacles.